# Open source .NET CMS that has admin user interface in Polish language

Tags: .net, open-source, content-management-system, polish

I need to set a website that is editable so I think that I should use some CMS. I am .NET developer so I prefer .NET CMS. This website is to be Polish website so everything on it should be in Polish language.

I have some experience with CMS and I already know that DotNetNuke has support for Polish language. But I don't want to use DNN cause it is not so easy to manage.

I know that I can write my own localization to most of available CMS, but I don't really have time for that. Or for translation of whole admin UI.

I don't need a lot of functionalities - only editable text on page, adding polls, photos, videos and comments.

So does anyone know any other open source **CMS** (preferably .NET) **that can have admin UI in Polish language**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a list of CMS systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems). Umbraco seems to be available in Polish.

Comment: Yes I think that I will choose Umbraco. Despite the fact that Polish translation is quite poor it has a lot of functionalities.